# Is there any way to give confidence as a parameter to pytesseract.image_to_string() for improvement of results?

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I have tried to find any config parameters for this but couldn't find.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It is always helpful to add some example input images and the results that you have received. This makes it more likely to get a useful answer. Here you find some more hints of [How to Ask!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no argument like confidence that you can pass to the pytesseract image_to_string().
The list of accepted arguments are:

```
image,
lang=None,
config='',
nice=0,
output_type=Output.STRING,
timeout=0
```

You can find the same in their official repo:
https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/pytesseract/pytesseract.py

Answer (score 0):

`pytesseract.image_to_string()` only returns a string of the text in the image.

I suggest using `pytesseract.image_to_data()` instead and get the text and confidence from the output dict.

Here's my implementation using tesseract 5.1 and pytesseract 0.3.10:

```
from statistics import fmean
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

data = pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open('<path_to_image>'), output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)
text = "".join(list(data.get('text')))
conf = fmean([numb for numb in data.get('conf') if numb > 0])
```